# .AspNetCore.Session Secure attribute is not coming

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, session-cookies

I am setting the the CookiePolicyOptions in the Configure method of `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    Secure = env.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.None : CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
});
```

but the secure attribute comes as blank in browser. I tried deploying it in different environment but this secure value does not come. Other Cookies like .AspNetCore.CookiesC1 comes with Secure attribute but not .AspNetCore.Session

[image: browser image]

Comment: What environment are you running? It looks like you've set no security policy when in `Development`.

Comment: Development is for my local but when it goes to stage and test env, security policies should reflect. Having issue with AspNetCore.session cookie, others are getting set.

Comment: Perhaps an issue of clearing the prior cookie?

Comment: I did try clearing my browser cookies, cache and when i add this code in my ConfigureServices method, AspNetCore.Session cookie is not showing under Cookies section in browser.

 services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            });

Comment: Try to add `options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;` when setting the session cookie. Otherwise it will not be set until the user accepts the cookie

Answer (score 1):

> I did try clearing my browser cookies, cache and when i add this code
> in my ConfigureServices method, AspNetCore.Session cookie is not
> showing under Cookies section in browser. services.AddSession(options
> => { options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; });

When you run project, you should indeed **clear the cache first**.

After you clear the cache, you need to trigger the code that uses the session to see the status of the `.AspNetCore.Session` cookie again.

You can add the use of Session to the default action such as '/home/index' code to test and get it in '/home/Privacy'.

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("a", 123);
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("a"));
        return View(a);
    }
```

Privacy.cshtml:

```
@model int
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>Use this page to detail your site's privacy policy.</p>

value: @Model
```

ConfigureServices：

```
 services.AddSession();
```

Configure:

```
          app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
            {

                Secure = env.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.None: CookieSecurePolicy.Always ,
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
            });
            app.UseSession();
```

For specific operations, please refer to the following：

**This is the test operation in `development environment`:**

[image]

**This is the test operation in `production environment(IIS)`:**

It should be noted that when you publish to the `production environment`, because you changed the `.AspNetCore.Session Secure` to `Always`, you need to choose **[https](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1#net-core-support-for-the-samesite-attribute)** instead of http.

[image]